# how to call the SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetail

Tags: c++, winapi, driver

I want to get the details info of special device' driver by the function "SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetailA". And my code like this:

```
            SP_DRVINFO_DATA_A sda;
            SP_DRVINFO_DETAIL_DATA_A sdda;
            memset(&sda, 0, sizeof(SP_DRVINFO_DATA_A));
            memset(&sdda, 0, sizeof(SP_DRVINFO_DETAIL_DATA_A));
            sda.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DRVINFO_DATA_A);
            sdda.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DRVINFO_DETAIL_DATA_A);
            DWORD aaa = 0;

            if (!SetupDiGetSelectedDriverA(hDevInfo, &deviceInfoData, &sda))
            {
                cout << "fail to exec the SetupDiGetSelectedDriverA()" << endl;
                return -1;
            }

            if (!SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetailA(hDevInfo, &deviceInfoData, &sda, &sdda, sizeof(sdda), &aaa))
            {
                auto res2 = GetLastError(); // 87
                cout << "fail to exec the SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetailA()" << endl;
                return -1;
            }
```

my issue is how to set the param, my code will always fail with GetLastError() 87(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER).

Comment: Are all the parameters in `SetupDiGetSelectedDriverA` valid?

Comment: Which device handle is `hDevInfo`?